# How can I start a Docker container and tell R to use a specific version of a system dependency being run in said container?

Tags: r, docker, gdal

I'm wanting to use the R package `MODIStsp` to download and process MODIS data, but currently there is an issue with GDAL's HDF4 driver package in my version of Linux (Manjaro). I've contacted the package maintainer, but in the mean time, I'd like to use a Dockerized version of GDAL on the backend to complete the task.

I know from within R it is possible to set the version of GDAL used ala

```
gdalUtils::gdal_setInstallation("/path/to/gdal/here")
```

My question is this: after I've pulled the `osgeo/gdal` image, how I can run the container in such a way to make it available to be used in R? And then how would the path get constructed in the function above?

Answer (score 1):

I would turn this around and look into setting up a Docker container that has the versions of `gdal` (and then `MODIStsp`) that work for you.

I just updated a machine this morning running Ubuntu 20.04 with the [usual PPA for CRAN packages](https://launchpad.net/%7Emarutter/+archive/ubuntu/c2d4u) (over 5000 of them) which relies on the underlying [UbuntuGIS-stable PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Eubuntugis/+archive/ubuntu/ppa).  That gave me, inter alia, `GDAL` 3.28 and `rgdal` 1.5-27 -- and I could just install `MODIStsp` 2.0.6 as a binary too.

I also have a couple of base container you could use for this, and could lend a hand if that is of interest.

Comment: Hi Dirk, thanks for this. If you have a base container you could point me to, that'd be really helpful, even if it doesn't have MODIStsp. I can just run the container interactively, install MODIStsp once inside, download the data, and then save it in a different format on my local disk using a Docker volume.

Comment: Your very best bet is [rocker/r-bspm:20.04](https://hub.docker.com/r/rocker/r-bspm) which is already setup for `bspm` so that it _automagically_ picks the `r-cran-modistsp` package for you when you add `Rscript -e 'install.packages("MODIStsp")'`. You likely have to add the one call `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntugis/ppa` to add the GIS PPA.